# Oracle custom row counter reset

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to create a row counter column by group in Oracle but I would like to reset this counter based on a value in the prior record.

I have for example:

```
+----------+---------+
| ID       | val     |
+----------|---------|
|123       | 1       |
|123       | null    |
|123       | 1       |
|123       | null    |
|123       | 1       |
|123       | null    |
|123       | null    |
|123       | null    |
| ...      | ....    |
+----------+---------+
```

what I would like:

```
+----------+---------+
| ID       |         |
+----------|---------|
|123       | 1       |
|123       | 2       |
|123       | 1       |
|123       | 2       |
|123       | 1       |
|123       | 2       |
|123       | 3       |
|123       | 4       |
|123       | 5       |
|...       | ...     |
+----------+---------+
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "prior" value without an order of some sort. Your table you show does not provide any column to order by.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent unordered sets, so presumingly your table should already have a column for sorting, namely call it `row_id` with uniquely defined values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9... while we want to generate a new column with incremented values which reset per each non-null value, then consider the following `SUM()` analytic function to be lately used as a partition critera within a `ROW_NUMBER()` function such as

```
SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY row_id) AS new_row_id
  FROM( SELECT t.*, 
               SUM(NVL2(val,1,0)) OVER (ORDER BY row_id) AS part
          FROM t)
 ORDER BY row_id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/4PBYN4eF)</kbd>